# Class inheritance with arbitrary number of **kwargs?

Tags: python, inheritance, init, self, keyword-argument

I'm trying to wrap my head around class inheritance, but I can't figure out how to get the **self** values from the Parent class to the Child class in an intuitive way. Ideally, I'd like to be using **kwargs because I may need to add additional keyword-variables to the Parent class.

```
class police_officer(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, age='40'):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class police_chief(police_officer):
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # What should put I here to inherit the __init__() values?


new_officer = police_officer(name='Danny')
chief = police_chief(new_officer)

print(chief.name)
```

Is my only option to explicitly call each variable  when I instantiate the **chief**? (example):

```
chief = police_chief(name=new_officer.name, age=new_officer.age)
```

Comment: `police_chief(new_officer)` - no, no, no. You don't make a superclass object and then build a subclass object around it.

Comment: I'm unsure how to make a new object that inherits from the parent class but keeps the same self values of the original object. Is there any way?

Comment: You don't make an "original object" at all.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you can leave off `__init__` in `police_chief` entirely.

```
class police_chief(police_officer):
    """A police officer who is chief."""
```

In a more general case where the police chief has additional setup to do in `__init__`, you'd probably use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
class police_chief(police_officer):
    def __init__(self, is_boss=True, **kwargs):
        super(police_chief, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.is_boss = is_boss
```

Be a little careful with super<sup>1</sup>.  [There are some pitfalls.](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).  However, if you follow [well established idioms](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), you'll be alright.  You could bypass it by doing `police_officer.__init__(self, **kwargs)` as well.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Really the problem isn't with `super` (per-se), it's more a problem with multiple inheritance.  For single inheritance, there are no pitfalls with super and no real differences between using it and calling the super-class method directly.</sup>

---

As you've mentioned, the way that you would then instantiate a police chief is by passing the `police_officer` arguments to the police chief constructor:

```
chief = police_chief(name=new_officer.name, age=new_officer.age)
```

If you want to be able to promote a police officer to a chief, you'd need to have an alternate constructor:

```
class police_chief(police_officer):
    @classmethod
    def promote(cls, officer, **kwargs):  # create_from_officer is probably a better name ...
        return cls(
            name=officer.name,
            age=officer.age,
            **kwargs)
```

Or perhaps restructure to the code to not use inheritance at all (and instead use some form of composition).

Comment: Or just `super()` in Python3. Come one, people, it's $CURRENTYEAR already!

Comment: It seems like a big part of my problem is that I cant pass classes around like I thought I could:

    new_officer = police_officer(name='Danny')
    chief = police_chief(new_officer)

How can I copy self attribute like name when promoting an officer to chief?

Comment: @Phil -- You do it explicitly.  See my most recent edits.

Comment: @o11c -- Yeah yeah.  Much of the world is still stuck in python2.x world so I try to be compatible with both wherever I can...

Comment: I see, let me see if I can rework my code to work in this way.

Comment: @mgilson The only world still stuck in python 2.x is the people who insist that the world is still stuck in python 2.x

Comment: @o11c -- That's not completely true.  For my part, I work on a project hosted on Google AppEngine.  While it is true that we could migrate to managed VMs (or whatever Google's calling them these days) which support python3.x, most of the AppEngine services cease to function and you have to build all of those from scratch which isn't really an option.  I'm very much looking forward to a day when Google releases a 3.x GAE runtime so we can switch to that...